# Compiling an already written C script. Visual Studios 2017

Tags: c

I have an already written script for C that I want to use to go along with Texmod. There was post about it a long time ago but I can't access it. Basically it lets you use TexMod with arguments for the .exe like -log. I have downloaded Visual Studios 2017 and have tried compiling it using the developers console by cd to the folder than cl 'script.c' to compile it. It makes an .exe and .obj but does nothing past that, even when I double click the .exe The problem is I know java and have never done anything in the C language. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <tlhelp32.h>

UINT WINAPI EzGetPid(LPCSTR procName, UINT *pid, UINT size);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc < 1) {
        puts("You must specifie the arguments");
        return 1;
    }

    UINT pid = 0;
    if (!EzGetPid("Texmod.exe", &pid, 1)) {
        puts("You must open Texmod first.");
        return 1;
    }

    BYTE shellcode_tramp[] = "\x58\x6A\x00\x6A\x00\x68\x00\x00\x00\x00\xFF\xE0";
    UINT size_tramp = 12;

    char arguments[0x500] = {0};
    strcpy(arguments, argv[1]);

    HANDLE proc = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, pid);
    LPVOID remote_tramp = VirtualAllocEx(proc, NULL, 0x1000, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
    LPVOID remote_args = (LPVOID)((DWORD)remote_tramp + size_tramp);

    *(DWORD*)(&shellcode_tramp[6]) = (DWORD)remote_args;
    WriteProcessMemory(proc, remote_tramp, shellcode_tramp, size_tramp, NULL); // Write the trampoline
    WriteProcessMemory(proc, remote_args, arguments, strlen(arguments), NULL); // Write the arguments

    BYTE firstCall[] = "\xE8\x00\x00\x00\x00\x90";
    BYTE secondCall[] = "\xE8\x00\x00\x00\x00\x90";
    *(DWORD*)(&firstCall[1]) = (DWORD)remote_tramp - 0x4012E1 - 5;
    *(DWORD*)(&secondCall[1]) = (DWORD)remote_tramp - 0x40145B - 5;
    WriteProcessMemory(proc, (LPVOID)0x4012E1, firstCall, 6, NULL); // Write first detour call
    WriteProcessMemory(proc, (LPVOID)0x40145B, secondCall, 6, NULL); // Write second detour call

    CloseHandle(proc);
    return 0;
}

UINT WINAPI EzGetPid(LPCSTR procName, UINT *pid, UINT size)
{
    HANDLE hSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
    PROCESSENTRY32 buffer = {0};
    buffer.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);

    UINT count = 0;

    while (Process32Next(hSnap, &buffer) && count < size) {
        if (!strcmp(buffer.szExeFile, procName))
        pid[count++] = buffer.th32ProcessID;
    }

    CloseHandle(hSnap);
    return count;
}
```

p.s. I added the last closed bracket as I thought I may have copied it wrong when I copied it long ago.

Do I need to use the Visual Studios interface to do this? I was wondering if someone that knows C could look at the code I'm trying to compile and help explain anything I am missing or any special instructions as to how to run it.
Thank you very much for all help.

Comment: The program requires arguments (see line 9). So you can't just double-click the executable. You have to run it from the command line (cmd.exe) with the argument.

Comment: C does not have "scripts".  That term is normally reserved for interpreted languages.  What you have presented is the source code for a *program*.

Comment: If you always want the same arguments then you could also create a desktop shortcut that runs the program and feeds it those arguments.

Comment: So this is where I am at. I run the compiled C# executable which I named: texmodarguments.exe by opening command prompt then cd to the directory then typing: texmodarguments - log, which is the launch argument I want but I don't get a log window and skin mod I am trying to run withTexMod won't work; though it will run the game when i press launch . So I am at a dead end right now. Am i putting in the arguments wrong? Is there something else anyone can think of that I may not be doing right? Thanks for all help

Comment: VS is one of many compilers which will work with Windows. The fact that you got an `.exe` means it's compiled. Now one has to figure out what it does.

Answer (score 0):

Your program requires arguments in order to run correctly.  The reason you're program doesn't do anything is because when double clicking it, you're not passing any arguments.  The console is closing before you see the debug message "You must specifie the arguments".

Typically it's much easier to deal with trampoline hooks using an internal injected DLL method rather than this external method.  You could start the process in a suspended state then inject your DLL to perform the trampoline hook.  Then you can easily modify the function arguments of the function you're hooking.

Here is the code I use for x86 trampoline hooks

```cpp
bool Detour32(BYTE* src, BYTE* dst, const uintptr_t len)
{
    if (len < 5) return false;

    DWORD curProtection;
    VirtualProtect(src, len, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &curProtection);

    uintptr_t relativeAddress = dst - src - 5;

    *src = 0xE9;

    *(uintptr_t*)(src + 1) = relativeAddress;

    VirtualProtect(src, len, curProtection, &curProtection);
    return true;
}

BYTE* TrampHook32(BYTE* src, BYTE* dst, const uintptr_t len)
{
    if (len < 5) return 0;

    //Create Gateway
    BYTE* gateway = (BYTE*)VirtualAlloc(0, len, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);

    //write the stolen bytes to the gateway
    memcpy_s(gateway, len, src, len);

    //Get the gateway to destination address
    uintptr_t gatewayRelativeAddr = src - gateway - 5;

    // add the jmp opcode to the end of the gateway
    *(gateway + len) = 0xE9;

    //Write the address of the gateway to the jmp
    *(uintptr_t*)((uintptr_t)gateway + len + 1) = gatewayRelativeAddr;

    //Perform the detour
    Detour32(src, dst, len);

    return gateway;
}
```

Here is an example of how I use it to took OpenGL's SwapBuffers function, in this example we will change the hDc argument to 1337.

```
typedef BOOL(__stdcall* twglSwapBuffers) (HDC hDc);

twglSwapBuffers owglSwapBuffers;

BOOL __stdcall hkwglSwapBuffers(HDC hDc)
{
    hDc = 1337;
    return owglSwapBuffers(hDc);
}

owglSwapBuffers = (twglSwapBuffers)mem::TrampHook32((BYTE*)owglSwapBuffers, (BYTE*)hkwglSwapBuffers, 5);
```